# Array to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm working on a little problem in JS (not graded or for school, just for practice), and can't seem to get it quite right.

The aim is to write a function that converts a multi-dimensional array to an array of objects. For example, the input could be:

```
var data = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
],
[
    ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
  ]
]
```

And this should be the output:

```
[
{firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
{firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  var object = {};
  var objectsArray = [];
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<array[i].length; j++) {
      var keys = array[i][j][0];
      object[keys] = array[i][j][1];
     }    objectsArray.push(object);
   } 
       return objectsArray);
 }
```

It's almost right, but I get this as output:

```
[ { firstName: 'Mary',
lastName: 'Jenkins',
age: 36,
role: 'manager' },
{ firstName: 'Mary',
lastName: 'Jenkins',
age: 36,
role: 'manager' } ]
```

How do I go about fixing the function so that it doesn't spit out the same thing twice?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried going through the code with a debugger, or with pen and paper? That way you can understand where the bug lies and fix it.

Comment: You can do it using `map` and `reduce` like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/vf0dp1rL/).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir—but that doesn't help the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates a single instance of an object, then overwrites the values in that instance.

To fix, create a new object every time:

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
    var objectsArray = [];
    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
       var object = {};
       for (j=0; j<array[i].length; j++) {
           var keys = array[i][j][0];
           object[keys] = array[i][j][1];
       }    
       objectsArray.push(object);
  } 
  return objectsArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought that was the problem, but didn't know what to do about it. Nice fix!

Answer (score 1):

you're only creating 1 instance of the object variable.
create a new instance ( object = {} ) inside the loop.

you are ovirriding the properties of the object each run, but actually using the same object.